# Can I force a TextView to not set his dimension in order to fill the background?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, textview, image-scaling

I need to put an image (downloaded via HTTP request) as a TextView's background programmatically.

On this image I have to change the scaleType (FIT_XY, CENTER, FIT_CENTER, ...). Since that TextView doesn't allow to set the scaleType, my idea was to:

- create an ImageView
- set the downloaded image as background to the ImageView
- set the ImageView's drawable as TextView's background

Unfortunately this approach doesn't work. I think that the TextView try to expand himself to bound the image.

Anyone can confirm my assumption?

Any possible solution?

**CODE ADDED**

```
ScaleType scaleType = ImageUtil.parseStretchOption(model.background.backgroundImageStretchOption);

ImageView iv = new ImageView(getContext());
iv.setScaleType(scaleType);
iv.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(getContext().getResources(), future.get()));                    

TextView view = new TextView(getContext());
view.setBackground(iv.getBackground());
```

Comment: can you post a bit of you code ?

Comment: @twntee I've added some code

Comment: layout too, brother !

Comment: @twntee 
I haven't layout, it's all programmatically because I need a dynamic view. The layout in which I add the views is a RelativeLayout.

Comment: then why not wrap the textView and imageview in another layout and thus add a background to that layout !

Comment: @twntee
Can you explain more clearly?